# How to sign_in user after devise email confirmation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I am trying from last 7 hours to auto signin the user after email confirmation but when I click the confirmation link then it says "Your email address has been successfully confirmed." but not sign in the user. I have written this code in my confirmations controller and route

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {confirmations: 'users/confirmations'}

class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  #private
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource)
    render plain: "here"
    redirect_to "/admins/view_account", notice: "User deleted."
  end
end
```

Any help would be highly appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have render plain: "here"?

Comment: @gates yes it is going inside confirmations controller

Comment: @gates ??? what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

Notice that automatically sign in after e-mail confirmation used to be Devise's default behavior and was then changed (after `3.1`) due to security measures as you can see more [here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18655887/1463744).

If you still want to do it, depending on the Devise's version make sure to set the line below on the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file within your project:

```
config.allow_insecure_sign_in_after_confirmation=true
```

If you are using latest Devise version, you may have to instead of that, extend the default controller with this code on `app/controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb` as a replacement of what you have mentioned above for controller code (**please mind the namespaces and path mentioned**):

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def show
    super do |resource|
      sign_in(resource) if resource.errors.empty?
    end
  end
end
```

And make sure the code you pasted in the beginning of the question belongs in `config/routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: 'users/confirmations' }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it myself.

routes should be like this

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: {confirmations: 'confirmations'} do
    #put "confirm_user", to: "confirmations#confirm_user"
    get "confirmation", to: "confirmations#after_confirmation_path_for"
  end
```

Controller is like this

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  #private
   def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource)
    #render plain: "here"
    #redirect_to "/admins/"
   end

  def show
    self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_flashing_format?
      sign_in(resource) # <= THIS LINE ADDED
      redirect_to "/your path/"
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity){ render :new }
    end
  end


end
```